# r squared based on columns from 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

i have 2 dataframes df1 and df2 , df1 is shown in the following code , and df2 is filled mean value in each column in each group , also as shown in the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Group':['1', '1', '2', '2'],
        'A':[1, 5, 15, 170],
        'B':[7, 12, 100.1, 14],
        'C':[2, 3.1, 6, 1],
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = df1.groupby("Group").transform(lambda x: x.mean())
```

i would like to calculate the value of R squared looping through the 2 dataframes and calculating the r squared each pair of columns , df1['A'] & df2['A'] , df1['B'] & df2['B'], .... the expected result is a dataframe filled with the value of Rsquared of columns A&A , B&B ....
thank you !

Comment: Can you write in your question what is the expected result?

Comment: I believe @BeChillerToo meant the _values_ of what you expected the Rsquared value of A & A to be. How many values, in what form, etc.

Comment: @HenryEcker in this case there will be 3 values , Rsquared of df1['A'] & df2['A'] , df1['B'] & df2['B'] & df1['C'] & df2['C'] , but resulted from a loop of columns from both tables

Comment: Okay and what are those three values? (The numeric values)

Comment: @HenryEcker in this particlular case A : 0.3998976573518216
B : 0.3780872668258889
C : 0.06442976976619663

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html#pandas-index-intersection) to get shared columns and [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html#scipy-stats-linregress) to get the `rvalue` then square it:

```
# Columns Shared By Both DataFrames
cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
# Iterate, Calculate, and Collect R-Squared Values
r_squared = {c: scipy.stats.linregress(x=df1[c], y=df2[c]).rvalue ** 2
             for c in cols}
```

`r_squared`:

```
{'A': 0.39989765735182164, 'B': 0.37808726682588906, 'C': 0.06442976976619669}
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats

data = {'Group': ['1', '1', '2', '2'],
        'A': [1, 5, 15, 170],
        'B': [7, 12, 100.1, 14],
        'C': [2, 3.1, 6, 1],
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = df1.groupby("Group").transform('mean')

# Columns Shared By Both DataFrames
cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)
# Iterate, Calculate, and Collect R-Squared Values
r_squared = {c: scipy.stats.linregress(x=df1[c], y=df2[c]).rvalue ** 2
             for c in cols}

print(r_squared)
```